# Android LinearLayout not displayed when more items in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

Android layout not display after listview if more item in list view.if i add 4 to 5 item my button is out of screen. and if i use 'android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"' then my linear layout is on last listview item.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sereen_2_bg" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/cartList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
         >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearCartFooter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/cartList"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/total"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtCartTotal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/total"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCartCheckout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sereen4_submit" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding `alignParentBottom="true"` to bottom layout and applying a bottom margin to list view like

```
android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
```

so that it does not overlap with my bottom layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add `'android:layout_alignParentTop="true"'` to your ListView and possibly `android:layout_below="@id/cartList"` to your Button if you want the ListView to be on top of the Layout and the bottom Views also visible all the time.

Comment: i did this but then my button is out of screen. and i cannot see them

Comment: Have you added alignParentBottom="true" to your bottom Layout?

Comment: yes i was solve this issue by adding alignParentBottom="true" to buttom layout and apply bottom margin to list view :)